# Add image in tab using Bootstrap directives for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have used bootstrap directive for angularjs for tab(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), 
and i found that it only support specific parameters

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs/docs

i want to know is there any way to set image instead of heading for bootstrap angularjs directive ?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs):

```
<tabset>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
        </tab-heading>
        Other tab content
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Practically you can put any content inside the `<tab-heading>`.